# How can I track sparse features using a dense optical flow approach like Farneback's?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, opticalflow

I can already track SIFT or SURF features using Lucas Kanade implemented in OpenCV, because Lucas Kanade tracks sparse features any way, however I am trying to use Farneback's optical flow algorithm implemented in OpenCV to track those sparse features, is there an algorithm for that?

[Realtime Dense Optical flow tracking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1D93RmW_eN4)

Please check this video:

The developers claim that they tracked the selected sparse features using a dense approach "Farneback" rather than a sparse approach "Lucas-Kanade". How did they do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To track a feature with a dense optical flow field `flow` can be done as follows:

```
// read images    
cv:Mat prevImg = cv::imread( filename0 ); // image data at time t
cv::Mat currImg = cv::imread( filename1 ); // image data at time t and t + 1
cv::Mat flowMat; // storage for dese optical flow field
std::vector<cv::Point2f> prevPoints; // points to be track

// initialize points to track (example)
prevPoints.push_back( cv::Point2f( 50.3f, 30.f ) );
std::vector<cv::Point2f> currPoints( prevPoints.size()); // tracked point position

 // compute dense flow field (example)
cv::calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevImg, currImg, flowMat, 0.4, 1, 12, 2, 8, 1.2, 0);

// track points based on dense optical flow field and bilinear interpolation
for( unsigned int n = 0; n < prevPoints.size(); ++n )
{
  float ix = floor(prevPoints[n].x);
  float iy = floor(prevPoints[n].y);
  float wx = prevPoints[n].x - ix;
  float wy = prevPoints[n].y - iy;
  float w00 = (1.f - wx) * (1.f - wy);
  float w10 = (1.f - wx) * wy;
  float w01 = wx * (1.f - wy);
  float w11 = wx * wy;
  if( prevPoints[n].x >= flowMat.cols - 1 || prevPoints[n].y >= flowMat.rows - 1)
  {
    // these points are out of the image roi and cannot be tracked.
    currPoints[n] = prevPoints[n];
  }
  else
  {
   /*
   bilinear interpolation of the flow vector from the flow field at a given location.
   The bilinear interpolation has to be applied since the points to track can be given at subpixel level 
   */
   currPoints[n] = prevPoints[n] 
                 + flowMat.at<cv::Point2f>(iy, ix) * w00 
                 + flowMat.at<cv::Point2f>(iy+1, ix) * w10 
                 + flowMat.at<cv::Point2f>(iy, ix+1) * w01 
                 + flowMat.at<cv::Point2f>(iy+1, ix+1) * w11;
  }
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am testing your code. One last question: flowMat.at<cv::Point2f>(iy, ix) * cv::Point2f(w00, w00) -> Is this element wise multiplication or a cross product? because this does not work in opencv.

Comment: Sorry I just realized that a cross product for 2D vectors has not meaning so I am assuming that you meant element wise multiplication.

Comment: Thanks it is kinda working but I had to fix some stuff

Comment: A sorry. I hope this is better now. I forget that cv::Point2f has an overload  multiply operator which used floats .

Comment: Thanks, aren't we supposed to accumulate the position:    currPoints[n] = currPoints[n] + (flowMat.at<cv::Point2f>(iy, ix) * w00 
                 + flowMat.at<cv::Point2f>(iy+1, ix) * w10 
                 + flowMat.at<cv::Point2f>(iy, ix+1) * w01 
                 + flowMat.at<cv::Point2f>(iy+1, ix+1) * w11);

Comment: Thanks, you are right but prevPoints[n] instead of currPoints[n]

Answer (score 0):

There is a function [calcOpticalFlowFarneback()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowfarneback) in OpenCV to do just that.

Comment: I know about this function, Farneback's method gives a motion field that is dense meaning for every pixel, however my question is how can I use Farneback's function to track a set of sparse key points or features.